# Semantic equivalence of reformatted (PL/)SQL code

Tags: sql, plsql, code-formatting, verification

## Background

Hundreds of database objects (views, packages, stored procedures, etc.) in a system have no formatting and no source code comments. We'd like to:

1. Automatically reformat the code (using the [General SQL Parser](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/category/general-sql-parser/)).
2. Automatically copy a standard comment header into each object's source file.

## Problem

We cannot push such sweeping changes into production without being tested.

## Question

How would you verify that the reformatted source code is functionally identical to the un-formatted code?

Thank you!

Comment: I strongly recommend you do not do this.  I would not trust any SQL or PL/SQL parser to do this.  Automatically formatting code is NOT a trivial task.

Comment: What possible benefit would this have? It's possible that some (maybe even a lot) of the code will never need to be significantly worked on or even looked at. The risk of regression would surely be too great in comparison with the perceived benefits. I'd rather use a slowly-but-surely approach: whenever you need to change an object, format it and add the standard header in *for that object*. Then, when your changes are tested, the reformatting is also tested at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

1. Run the unformatted code against a fresh new database
2. Run the formatted code against a fresh new database
3. Do a full export of both and compare the two files

They should be identical.

The reason they should be identical is that postgres parses the SQL into its standard, canonical form, so even adding unnecessary brackets for example should result in the same internal version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that format is required only for those objects that need to be modified, if so I recomend format only the object you are working on that at the end the result should be put into production. I use Oracle SQL Developer and is safe for me to work on a program unit and do format.

Answer (score 0):

To your question: to compare formatted source code with un-formatted you will have to tokenize each of them and compare results. Which in - fact defeat your original objective. ;-)